# Can I bring back my Form1 if it lost or moved?

Tags: c#, file, backup, missing-features

I am a novice c# coder using visual studio 2015. When I open the project most of the code and design are missing. My design view and code for Form1 have disappeared but I can still see that they exist in my solution explorer. When I try to view them through the solution explorer I am met with an error that says the file cannot be found because it has been moved or deleted.

More specifically it says "Cannot find the file 'C:\Users\Brand\Documents\Visual studio 2015\Backup Files\Form1.Designer.cs'. It may have been moved or deleted.

Is there any way for me to fix the project without redoing it entirely?

Comment: Likely the files are indeed deleted, but references of them still exist in your project file. So navigate to the folder to see if the files are indeed deleted. If so, maybe an undelete from the trash can will fix your issue.

Comment: When I go to debug the program it states there are build errors and if I would like to run it from the last successful build. If I say click yes it shows the entire project including the missing parts and runs perfectly.